# Layout issue Android Studio

Tags: android, layout

what is the problem here ?
When I run the app , I do not get  the same result as the Design part ..
Any recommendations ?

[image]

Here is the xml code behind , i'm using the Pixel XL API 28 (Android 9, API 28)

[image]

Comment: Please post the XML for your layout. And what API version are you using in the emulator?

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: I just edited the my message , here is the xml code , my API version is : Pixel XL API 28 (Android 9, API 28)

Comment: I'd suggest you use a `<LinearLayout>` with `android:orientation:vertical`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using constraint layout and form the look of it you are laking the vertical constraint so your views are jumping into the top of your screen(they don't have anchor point to hold on to).
**Here is an example of a similar layout with the vertical constraint:**

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="129dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="UserName"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="226dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="password"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: please i didn't really understand , what should i exactly change in my code and why ?

Comment: Ok, you posted a picture of your code so its kind of hard to tell just from it but - when your views are all jumping to the top of the screen like this than it is probably because you don't have a vertical constraint. And when you don't have vertical constraints your views can't tell where to place themselves vertically so they are automatically pushed to the top of the screen, in my example the are those missing constraints attached.

Comment: OH thank you it worked now !

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to your namespaces while declaring XML layouts. `android` is the namespace being used to render your layout on Android while `tools` **only used to modify rendering your layout in Android studio layout editor**. So they'll not be compiled to use on runtime.

Bottom line is consider your layout without `tools` attributes as the actual one.

Comment: Interesting answer - I want to ask when will I use `tools` attributes? from what you wrote I see no point of putting them in the layouts, any other place that will be good for them?

Comment: A good example is when you need to fill your views with some sample data to illustrate a filled preview of your views in actual use. Like using `tools:text` for adding a sample text to you `TextView`s or `tools:src` for `ImageView`s.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me something new

Comment: Glad to help :)